# Javers fragment not having a jv_global_id record

Tags: javers

I committed an object in javers and it created the initial records in the table, except I've noticed one thing:

In the jv_snapshot table, I have the following state of object Person (recorder):

```
{
  "firstName": "test",
  "lastName": "test",
  "address": {
      "valueObject": "x.model.Address",
      "ownerId": {
        "entity": "x.Place",
        "cdoId": 99999
      },
    "fragment": "recorder/address"
    },
    "organisation": {
       "valueObject": "x.model.Organisation",
       "ownerId": {
          "entity": "x.Place",
          "cdoId": 99999
        },
        "fragment": "recorder/organisation"
      },
    ...
}
```

Organisation is of ValueObject, and I made sure that it has a value before committing it with javers however when I checked jv_global_id, there's no record with the fragment "recorder/organisation". The other objects under Person and other Organisation objects associated to entity Place was audited properly. When I view the shadow of that commit, the place.recorder.organisation object is null.

When I edit the place -> person (recorder) -> organisation object and commit it in javers, that's when the INITIAL type record for managed_type "recorder/organisation" is saved, which shouldn't be because it's an update. So when I view the shadow of the first commit, it would display the value of the second commit.

If I change the Organisation to entity object, it would save the initial value, but I want to avoid that because we only want to maintain one entity (which is Place).

Aaand this doesn't happen to all place objects. Some objects store a "recorder/organisation" fragment on first commit Am I missing anything? Is there anything I should check?

I use MSSQL, and also Spring JPA.

Comment: this question is unclear, could you specify your expectations versus reality in a runnable test case? See how we write specs in JaVers - https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/examples/JqlExample.groovy

Comment: Will try to create a test case and see if I could duplicate the error. The problem is, it's a bit intermittent so I was wondering if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Still not able to create a test case but found out how to replicate issue. If an entity has 2 value objects with the same object (i.e. Entity User, Value Object 1: Address State1, Value Object 2: Address State1), I would get a null value for Value Object 2